# Reload on Solr (Google Cloud)

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, commit

I was having issues with submitting a document into Solr on Google Cloud and read somewhere that the issue should be resolved by committing.

I couldn't figure out how to commit on Solr(noob) and pressed a button called reload. The error went away, but I'm afraid I messed something else up. Can anyone explain what reload does compared to commit, or confirm if reload was fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, reload isn't fine if you want a commit.

The reload command tells solr to update some core based on a new configuration (solrconfig, schema and another config files). Even if it work in your case, it's not meant for the purpose of commit.

The commit command tells solr that the data sent to it should be searchable ASAP. I guess it's what you're looking for.
For this you can configure automatic commits and/or soft commits in solrconfig.xml. There's also a URL you can call to achieve this, which is something like this: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true

I recommend you to read this docs:

[Commit](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updatehandlers-in-solrconfig.html)

[Reload](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html)